# Can I print a CSS style property to the console using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Got another basic question that I couldn't seem to find the answer for online. I can change the CSS property of an element easily using javascript,

```
 document.getElementById("ExampleID").style.height="30px";
```

however whenever I try printing a property to the console, with

```
console.log(document.getElementById("ExampleID").style.height);
```

it prints a blank line instead of the property. How can I print a style property value of the desired element? Thank you very much

Comment: Works fine for me, is there anything else that could cause the problem?

Comment: Does the `ExampleID` element have inline styles applied when you try to console log them? Styles defined in CSS can not be accessed with `Element.style`.

Comment: No it doesn't, they are modified using CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('test');
let ht = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("height");
console.log(ht)
```

```css
.test {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are testing with an actual element that will be returned from your selection (see example below). Otherwise your code is fine.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('elemId');
elem.style.height = '30px';

console.log(elem.style.height);
```

```html
<div id="elemId"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check HTML part in this case.

1. If you are setting from javascript then Your code is working fine.
2. In case Styles defined in CSS use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

   > The window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object that reports the values of all CSS properties of an element after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.  Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object or by simply indexing with CSS property names.

Here is working snippet:

```js
var divEle=document.getElementById("ExampleID");
console.log("Before:height::"+divEle.style.height);
console.log("Before:color::"+divEle.style.color);

var  heightCss = window.getComputedStyle(divEle, null).getPropertyValue("height");
var  colorCss = window.getComputedStyle(divEle, null).getPropertyValue("color");

console.log("Before:height from css::"+heightCss)
console.log("Before:color from css::"+colorCss)

function changeCss(){
divEle.style.height="30px";
divEle.style.color="blue";

console.log("After:height::"+divEle.style.height);
console.log("After:color::"+divEle.style.color);
}
```

```css
.divClass {
  height: 40px;
  color: red;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="divClass" id="ExampleID">test</div><div><input type="button" onClick="changeCss();" value="Change Css"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("ExampleID").style.height="30px";
console.log(document.getElementById('ExampleID').clientHeight);
console.log(document.getElementById('ExampleID').offsetHeight);
```

```html
   
<div id="ExampleID">
clientHeight includes padding.<br>
offsetHeight includes padding, scrollBar and borders.
</div>
```

- clientHeight includes padding.
- offsetHeight includes padding, scrollBar and borders.

Comment: Would this work for other properties as well? Such as margin values, padding, etc?

Comment: The `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: Yes you can use console.log(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.marginLeft), marginRight, marginTop etc

Comment: @Rob, Yes i forgot, i will fix it