# Why can't I console.log () style.display

Tags: javascript, html, css, console.log

I have problems trying to console.log () the display value of menucontent but can't even though I have selected correctly, please check it for me, thanks

```
clickMenuReponsive.onclick = function(){
    let menuContent = document.querySelector('nav .menu .menu-content');
    console.log(menuContent);
    console.log(menuContent.style.display);
}
```

```
nav .menu .menu-content {display: none; margin-top: 10px}
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51639047/1848929

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

To get the styles which are ***not inline*** of an element you can use [**`window.getComputedStyle()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

**Demo:**

```js
let menuContent = document.querySelector('.menu-content');
console.log(menuContent);
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(menuContent).display);
```

```css
.menu-content {display: none; margin-top: 10px}
```

```html
<li class="menu-content">Text</li>
```