# i am trying to get the style of an element from html and trying to print on console

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

i am trying to get the style of an element from html and trying to print on console. I cant see style option while typing the style property in visual code. its keep showing the error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
in javascript  var element; element = document.querySelector("#header").style.backgroudColor; console.log(element);

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='all.css'>
    <script src="javascript_code.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header" class="heading" style="background-color: red;">
      <h1>this is header</h1>
      <h1>this is header2</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript_code.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your JavaScript in your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664045/how-to-get-an-html-elements-style-values-in-javascript Would help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638974/can-i-print-a-css-style-property-to-the-console-using-javascript

Comment: var element;
element = document.querySelector("#header").style.backgroudColor;
console.log(element);

Answer (score 0):

you have included javascript file two time first in the header and second at the last inside body tag. first remove one of them and there is a spelling mistake in backgroundColor as you can see here  `element = document.querySelector("#header").style.backgroundColor = 'green'`;

Comment: but the error still there. and i am jest getting the value from html document.

Comment: the reason is in the `element` variable you have assign value only. If you want to assign an element inside the variable the code will be  `element = document.querySelector("#header");` than only you can get actual element inside your variable.

Comment: After assign the element inside the variable you can add style. first `element = document.querySelector("#header");` than second  `element.style.backgroundColor = 'green';`

Comment: var element;
element = document.querySelector("#header");
var e2=element.style.backgroudColor;
console.log(e2);

Comment: still getting undefined.

Comment: look at this video at 2:00 minutes. it works for him but not for me    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeuPPUjY4kQ

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.getElementById('header').style.backgroudColor` like this.

Answer (score 0):

i restarted the computer and all my snippets started working. the style property is now working.